# absolute path with react, react-app-rewire and typescript

Tags: reactjs, webpack

i'm using `create-react-app` + typescript, and i want to add absolute paths.

i'm trying to get to the point i can use absolute paths, like so:

instead of `import x from '../../../components/shell/shell'`

use `import x from '@components/shell/shell'`;

here is **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "extends": "./paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I'm using extended file for paths, because from some reason `npm start` overrides the file.
so is **paths.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@": ["./src"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*]"
    }
  }
}
```

i also have an **.env** file:

```
NODE_PATH=src
```

i installed `react-app-rewire` so i can config the paths,
and my *config-ovverrides.js* file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  paths: function(paths, env) {
    // ...add your paths config
    return paths;
  }
};
```

im stuck with connecting all the dots, it doesn't work and i still cant see what i need to do in order to config the webpack path object;

how can i implement paths in cra, ts, and rewire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve it using **5** simple steps **withou eject**:

**Step 1**: Adding react-app-rewired into your `devDependencies`.


`yarn add -D react-app-rewired` or `npm intall react-app-rewired --save-dev`

**Step 2**: After installation, you'll be able to change `package.json` default ReactsJS scripts to:

```
"scripts": {  
  "start": "react-app-rewired start",  
  "build": "react-app-rewired build",  
  "test": "react-app-rewired test",  
  "eject": "react-app-rewired eject" 
}
```

**Step 3**: Creates a new file called `tsconfig.paths.json` on root path, with content like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "services/*": ["./src/shared/services/*"],
      "interfaces/*": ["./src/shared/interfaces/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Tip 1**: you can choose which path you want to use, like:
`@services, @interface, @src, ~, @, etc` just by changing the keys inside `"paths": {}`

The same is applied to it's value: `["src/shared/services/"], ["src/shared/interfaces/"], ["src/*"]`, use the relative path here.

**Step 4**: Into `tsconfig.json`, before `"compilerOptions"` you need to extends the `tsconfig.paths.json` you just created.


Like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  ...//rest of file infos compilerOptions, include... whatever
}
```

**Step 5**: Creates a new file `config-overrides.js`, adding your alias and relative paths on it:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function override(config) {
  config.resolve = {
    ...config.resolve,
    alias: {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      'services': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/shared/services'),
      'interfaces': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/shared/interfaces')
    },
  };

  return config;
};
```

**Tip 2**: If you're using `eslint`, remember to have an `.eslintignore` file and add `config-overrides.js` within it.


Restart your IDE or text editor, in my case VSCode.

It's **DONE!** Now just run `yarn start` or `npm run start`

Comment: you're forgetting jest configuration

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use the `@` syntax?

Are you able to use the syntax of:

```
import x from 'components/shell/shell'
```

?

If so, then see the documentation for [CRA Absolute Imports](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports).

For Typescript, your `tsconfig.json` becomes:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... usual options ...
    "baseUrl": "src",
  },
  // ... include, etc...
}
```

Out of the box, this will allow you to import for `src` as the base directory.

So your syntax becomes:

```js
import x from 'components/shell/shell';
```

This would be the least friction option...

However...

If you absolutely need the `@` syntax, then to get rewire to work correctly requires a little more jiggery-pokery. The only way that I have found to get rewire to work with that syntax is to include a webpack alias rewrite.

So the process is (please update the paths as required for your application):

1. Create a `tsconfig.paths.json`next to your `tsconfig.json` containing:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components": ["src/components/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

2. Update your `tsconfig.json` with an `extend`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... standard options ...
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json"
}
```

When running the build command (`npm run build`), the scripts will throw the following error:

```
The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)
```

The extend option mitigates against this.

3. Add a webpack alias to `config-overrides.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const { override, addWebpackAlias } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  addWebpackAlias({
    '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
  })
);
```

This example uses the package `customize-cra` which has a bunch of helpful resolvers for overrides. (If you don't want to use it, then you would need to set the `config.resolve.alias` property on the `config` object passed to the `override` function)

Now assuming you have updated all the scripts to use `react-app-rewired`, you should be able to use the syntax:

```js
import x from '@components/shell/shell';
```

Comment: Hi,thanx for your answer.

I don't necessarily have to use '@'.

Answer (score 0):

**Path aliases are no longer supported**

But you can do this now to directly import files relative to the `src` directory

go to your `tsconfig.json` file add `baseUrl` to be `"."`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl":".",
    ...
```

then you can directly import stuff from the `src` directory

```
import Myfile from "src/myfile.js"
```

**This worked for me!**