# typescript absolute paths not working with js or jsx files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

When i compile my react project, typescript files are not able to resolve any files with js or jsx extensions unless the extension is explicitly specified when using absolute paths.

Folder Structure:

- src

  - constants

    - index.js
    - sample.js
  - pages

    - component.tsx

TSConfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "module": "esNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "paths": {
      "@pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
      "@common/*": ["src/common/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"]
    },
    "pretty": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(directory.src, 'node_modules')
        ],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css', '.scss'],
        plugins: [new TsConfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: path.resolve(directory.src, 'tsconfig.json') })]
    },

module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                loader: 'source-map-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jsx|js|ts|tsx)?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                include: path.resolve(directory.src, './src'),
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'thread-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            happyPackMode: true,
                            transpileOnly: true,
                            experimentalWatchApi: true,
                            configFile: currentTSConfig
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            //other modules
```

```
import { ElementIds } from '@common/constants'; // Doesnt work
import { ElementIds } from '@common/constants/index'; // Doesnt work
import { ElementIds } from '@common/constants/index.js'; // Works
```

Not sure what i am missing here but typescript cant seem to recognize any of the js or jsx files unless the extension is specified. This seems to be an issue only when using absolute paths.

Comment: You have to look at your loader which are you using first since it's combined both `ts-loader` + `babel-loader` which is supposed to be used one of them to determine where error comes from `balel` or `tsc`

Comment: Do you get errors if you use typescript just to type check your project? Like `tsc -- noEmit --project TSconfigpath`

Comment: Updated the config to just use ts-loader. The error still pops up.

Comment: Try to use these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63605572/14172763 I believe it may help you.